# Flask Session Missing

Tags: flask

I'm recently working on Flask.

Here's the Code(Sample):

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'f_left.asp' in str(resp.content):
            session['user'] = request.form['stdid']
            flash('login success!')
            return render_template('index.html')
        else:
            error = 'invaild username or password'
            return render_template('index.html', error=error)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        if 'redirect' in session:
            error = session['redirect']
            session.pop('redirect', None)
            return render_template('index.html', error=error)
        else:
            return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return 'method not allowed', 405

@app.route('/scoreboard/')
def scoreboard():
    if 'user' in session:
        head, bodyhead, bodycontent, footer, rank = crawler()
        return render_template('scoreboard.html', head=head,bodyhead=bodyhead, bodycontent=bodycontent)
    else:
        session['redirect'] = 'login first!'
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

The session `user` sometimes will disappear after I login.
It annoys me for a while and still don't have any clues to it :(

(or should i just use flask-login)

Comment: Don't rely on a simple session parameter to identify users. I think you'll find something like Flask-Login most useful: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `if 'f_left.asp' in str(resp.content):` seems unusual-- what are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @AArias Ok, Thanks a lot

Comment: @Doobeh Noting suspicious. It's just a crawler site :p